# Jersey Rest Asynchronous response

Tags: rest, asynchronous, jersey

I am trying to get the response back immediately from the method below and proceed with rest of the process. But I don't see my return value "TestAync" anytime. Can you please suggest on how to retrieve (client code) response from the below call.

Here is the client call I am making, appreciate your help.
Future response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://localhost:8080/testasync/test/async/test5").request().async().get();

```
@GET
@Path("async/{echo}")
public String asyncEcho(@PathParam("echo") final String echo, @Suspended final AsyncResponse ar) {
    TASK_EXECUTOR.submit(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_IN_MILLIS);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ar.cancel();
            }
            ar.resume(echo);
        }
    });
    return "TestAysnc";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the async case the return value (`TestAsync`) is ignored because JAX-RS runtime (e.g. Jersey) expects that the entity that is sent back to the client would be provided via [AsyncResponse#resume(Object)](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/AsyncResponse.html#resume(java.lang.Object)) call.

In your particular case `test5` would be returned to the client since you're resuming asynchronous response with this string object.

For more info take a look at [Asynchronous Server API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e8750) in Jersey User Guide or read the [JAX-RS 2.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Michal, is there any way I can implement Asynchronous using rest and return the value before it proceeds with rest of the task. I tried many options but ended creating Executor Threads for the tasks and return the value (ACK) to the client. (This is completely my custom implementation of Asynchronous approach). Please let me know if this is a recommend option.